# How to implement tf.argmax on our own?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I want to use a function which takes as input a tensor and Returns the index with the largest value across axes of a tensor. I know there exists a function tf.argmax() that does exactly the same, but how do I implement it on my own (this may be necessary incase of implementing some custom function)?

Let us suppose for now the function takes as input only 1D tensor. So, the function needs to be of following signature:

```
argmax(
    input, #input is a 1D tensor
    name=None
)
```

I tried implementing it this way:

```
def argmax(input, name=None):
    maxValue=0
    maxIndex=0
    for i in range(input.get_shape()[0]):
        if input[i]>maxValue:
            maxValue=input[i]
            maxIndex=i
    return maxIndex
```

However this does not work since during the construction phase, the values are not yet intialized and hence I cannot compare two values as I did in the above code. So, is there a way where we can write out custom functions like tf.argmax, tf.equal, etc?

Comment: SO is not a free coding site. Being the virtual embodiment of the site itself, I'm surprised you were not aware of that.

Comment: @Mad Physicit I have added the code that i tried, but it doesn't work..

Comment: You can look at the source of the corresponding tf functions and see what it does. Otherwise, I'm not even sure what you're asking or why.

Comment: I cannot since function tf.equal are autogenerated from C++ code

Answer (score 0):

Well, one simple way would be this:

```
idx = tf.where(tf.equal(input, tf.reduce_max(input)))[0, 0]
```

Example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
    input = tf.constant([1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2])
    idx = tf.where(tf.equal(input, tf.reduce_max(input)))[0, 0]
    print(sess.run(idx))
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: Ok..this means that we have to rely on other tf functions...right? Since tf.equal() cannot be implemented by us..is there a way to implement functions like tf.argmax, tf.equal totally from scratch?

Comment: @SubrajitMallick I'm not sure I understand what you mean... All the operations in TensorFlow are functions... even the basic operations (`+`, `*`, etc) are just special class methods (`__add__`, etc). You can think of alternatives (e.g. a loop with `tf.while_loop`, which would be slower though), but as long as you are operating with TF objects you need to use TF code (and even if you evaluate a tensor, you would be dealing with NumPy functions...). What would be an example of something you consider to be "totally from scratch"?

Comment: @SubrajitMallick The whole idea of Tensorflow API in python is to give access to an efficient implementation of these operations, alongside a large toolbox of great features that google developers had worked hard to give us. You can also tensorflowify python functions but should be your last resort. You can also write the whole computational graph API from scratch, with autograd and stuff, but again, why reinvent the wheel? just improve it or invent something else.